# Splitting a single FLAC file into songs with a Cue sheet?

Tags: recording, digital-audio, audio-software

I've got a complete CD which is one large FLAC file.  I also have a Cue sheet, which could be used with certain CD burning software (such as ImgBurn) to allow the CD to be split into tracks.

What I want to do is split the FLAC into song files based on the Cue sheet.  I could have sworn I did this before but can't remember which audio editing software allowed me to do so.  Worst-case scenario is I have to split it by hand (by putting in chapter points), but if I can get this done automatically I can save some time and effort.

Any ideas on how to split a FLAC file based on a Cue sheet?

Comment: http://cue.tools/wiki/CUETools ?

Comment: @BCdotWEB: CUETools works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've discovered a solution which works quite nicely; Foobar2000.  The application itself is available here:

https://www.foobar2000.org/FAQ

I discovered this via google on a messageboard.  I'll add that link here as it discusses some of what's necessary to do this:

https://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=89792

In particular:

> Thanks for the help!
>   I finally had some time to try out foobar2000. I have downloaded the LAME 3.98.4 Bundle along with FLAC 1.2.1b from the links above and unzipped/installed them into two different folder.
>   I put the cuesheet into foobar and it showed the single tracks, i selected all of them and clicked on Convert: FLAC, level 8. then selected the FLAC.exe i have installed before. It did split the FLAC file to tracks.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested several options to split flac album files into flac song files using cue sheets and wasn't happy with the results. So I coded [albumSplitter](https://github.com/Puckid/albumSplitter): a python script that split the given album files into songs and also write the tags found in the cue sheet. You can also give it an album cover to be embedded in the files. Downside is that it doesn't have any GUI, but it's pretty easy to use for anyone with minimum knowledge of the command line.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth after all this time, I use [Flacon](http://flacon.github.io/) for this.