# How to make a CUE file fit for classical music?

Tags: classical-music, audio-software

Recently I've been exploring the treasure trove that is [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/audio) and its rich lodes of public domain classical music. For example try searching

```
creator:(Vivaldi) AND NOT title:(four seasons) AND collection:(unlockedrecordings) AND mediatype:(audio)
```

The best audio quality comes in FLAC format, usually one big fat file per side of the original record. In order to shoehorn this into my music player (To wit: [Clementine](http://www.clementine-player.org/), but the issue would be the same for any), I thus embark on a circuitous and perilious workfow that involves, *inter alii*, [Flacon](http://flacon.github.io/) and [Ex Falso](https://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/).

So as to know where to cut, Flacon demands to be feed a [CUE sheet](https://github.com/libyal/libodraw/blob/main/documentation/CUE%20sheet%20format.asciidoc), possibly hand-knit.
I can't seem to fathom how to handle the idea of a `composer` therein. In the same vein, it looks as if cue files, or for that matter digital media players, were designed for pop music and overlook the classical taxonomy where one work (e.g. concerto) has an overall title and is then divided into several movements (e.g. allegro, adagio, presto). Likewise, instead of listing some `performer`, it could seem relevant to specify the soloist, the conductor as well as the overall formation (e.g. Keith Jarrett, Dennis Russell, Stuttgarter Kammerorchester). `musicbrainz.org` seems to do it well, if perhaps too well. Anyway there seem to be no straightforward way from there to a cue file that Flacon could digest nor to metadata that a player could intelligently render.

Long story short, below is the latest cue sheet I produced, from [this archive](https://archive.org/details/lp_beethoven-auf-der-orgel_ludwig-van-beethoven-wilhelm-krumbach/). Question: how would we indicate the composer ?

Optional question: what do we do with [the notion of album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Album) in such a case ? (I can't find a polite way to be accurate here).

```
PERFORMER "Wilhelm Krumbach"
TITLE "Auf Der Orgel"
FILE "1.flac" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Suite Für Ein Orgelwerk WoO 33 - Adagio"
    INDEX 00 00:00:00
    INDEX 01 00:07:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "Suite Für Ein Orgelwerk WoO 33 - Scherzo"
    INDEX 01 06:04:00
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "Suite Für Ein Orgelwerk WoO 33 - Allegro"
    INDEX 01 08:14:00
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "Trio E-Moll - Adagio"
    INDEX 01 10:44:00
  TRACK 05 AUDIO
    TITLE "Trio E-Moll - Fuge"
    INDEX 01 16:08:00
  TRACK 06 AUDIO
    TITLE "Präludium F-Moll WoO 55"
    INDEX 01 20:37:00
  TRACK 07 AUDIO
    TITLE "Fuge C-Dur"
    INDEX 01 23:36:00
  TRACK 08 AUDIO
    TITLE "(RoF)"
    INDEX 01 26:09:00
```

NB:

1. The above query should yield [this](https://archive.org/search?query=creator%3A%28Vivaldi%29%20AND%20NOT%20title%3A%28four%20seasons%29%20AND%20collection%3A%28unlockedrecordings%29%20AND%20mediatype%3A%28audio%29).
2. [Similar question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/splitting-a-single-flac-file-into-songs-with-a-cue-sheet) in `musicfans.stackexchange.com`
3. [Related](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/11953/classical-pieces-in-a-number-of-movements-what-in-general-connects-them)